# Logitech Options smooth scrolling and Chrome smooth scrolling

Tags: google-chrome

I have Logitech mouse and Logitech Options software. In Logitech Options I set smooth scrolling "enabled".

In Chrome browser chrome://flags/ I have smooth scrolling "default".

I want smooth scrolling to be enabled and work well.

Should I have "default", "enabled" or "disabled" in Chrome flags?

I ask because I am not sure if Logitech Options smooth scrolling and Chrome smooth scrolling work well together. I am not sure if both is enabled if it doesn't counteract.

Answer (score 1):

Logitech smooth scrolling controls your input.

Chrome smooth scrolling controls the output/display.

I don't think they can conflict.

As regarding the Chrome flag, the setting you want is probably Enabled.
The Default setting also has smooth scrolling enabled, but it could automatically disable smooth scrolling when you have too many tabs open.